# PUT Request Does Not Run Knex Update Syntax And Does Not Throw Any Error, Keeps Loading In POSTMAN. (Knex.js , PostgreSQL, Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

> ```
> After creating an endpoint that handles a PUT request, I followed the knex documentation
> to update the record in the database, the result I get when I test using POSTMAN is:
> it keeps loading forever, I don't get any error or message in the terminal. But when I 
> console.log(req.body) it shows in the terminal the JSON sent from POSTMAN is hitting the 
> endpoint and I can see the data. I created other endpoints for GET requests using knex > 
> documentation and it is working fine except for the PUT method. I have attached 3 
> images; the first shows how POSTMAN keeps loading forever, and the
> second shows the data I sent from POSTMAN being logged in the
> terminal. And the code showing the endpoint and knex syntax.
> ```

[image]
[image]

[image]

> I want to have knex update the record that matches the id of the
>   record with the data it receives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I made some syntax errors.

```
app.put('/update', (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.body)
    const { id, name, year, house, mobile, email, occupation, gender} = req.body
    db.select('*')
        .from('unity_gate')
        .where('id', '=', id)
        .update({name: name, year: year, house: house, mobile: mobile, occupation: occupation,
            gender: gender, email: email})
        .then(data => res.status(200).json('Success'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
})
```